# mysql query for umlauts/special characters AND entities

Tags: mysql, special-characters, html-entities

in our database text can unfortunately be stored with umlauts or the html-equivalent so I'm trying to do a query like
`SELECT * FROM web_shop WHERE  text LIKE '%weiß%' OR text LIKE '%wei&szlig;%'`
but it seems to ignore everything behind the "&" because I am also getting results where the text is e.g. "Art und Weise".

UPDATE
Here is how the table is created:

`
    phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
    version 3.5.8.2
    http://www.phpmyadmin.net

```
Host:  
Server Version: 5.5.37-0+wheezy1  
PHP-Version: 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.12  

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";  
SET time_zone = "+00:00";  


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabellenstruktur für Tabelle 'web_shop'
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'web_shop';
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'web_shop' (
  'id' int(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'text' text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('id')
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=126 ;
```

`

Comment: Try to set the encoding  of your table or databank  like this.  "SET NAMES UTF8;"

Comment: There is no Unmlaut in the string? and there is also no `&` in the string that`s why you got no result.

Comment: Sorry with Umlaut I also mean the sharp-s (ß) character=special character

Comment: @Jens: I'm getting a result, that's the problem. Text with "Art und Weise" is found which shouldn't be found when searching for "weiß" and "wei&szlig;".

Comment: @TomSenner in your example is also no `ß`. There are only ascii character in `"Art und Weise"`

Comment: @Jens: Yes there is a "ß". Please look at my SELECT-Query above. My query has a "ß" but the result has not and that's the problem!

Comment: @TomSenner OK no i understand the problem. Can you pleas add the ddl of your table `web_shop`?

Comment: @Jens: Sorry what do you mean by ddl, the Kollation of the table (Format:dynamisch,Kollation:latin1_swedish_ci) the field text(utf8_general_ci)

Comment: @TomSenner The database definition. How the table is created.

Comment: @Jens: MyISAM (hope that's what you mean)

Comment: @TomSenner No I need the whole create statement of the table.